# MultiMarkdown processors: Fonts?

Tags: fonts, libreoffice, markdown

I just found MultiMarkdown, which is awesome. I've installed the GitHub official application from https://github.com/fletcher/MultiMarkdown-6 on my Gentoo box, and I'm using it to create HTML pages and ODT documents. My question is, can I set different fonts to use for default text, (optional) header text, and monospace code? At the moment, I have to use LibreOffice and manually go through the text changing fonts (I want to change it to a Roboto and Fira Code combination for default and code text respectively). Is there any way to do this easily from within the MultiMarkdown parser or is there a way to programmatically replace fonts used within the ODT document?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know MMD but it looks like for the HTML you can do this using CSS. However, it has no effect for the ODT output.
The sample document [sample.txt](https://github.com/fletcher/MultiMarkdown-Gallery/blob/master/Sample-Document/sample.txt) has a metadata entry at the start:

```
CSS:    http://fletcherpenney.net/css/document.css
```

and that link eventually returns CSS such as (much edited):

```
body { font: 14px/1.5em Georgia, Palatino, Times; }
h1, h2, h3, h4 {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
}
span.logo {
  font-family: Didot, AppleMyungjo, Palatino, Times;
}
```

You would have to write your own css definitions.

---

For ODT it seems MMD just inserts a standard style-sheet. Since a .odt file is a zip archive of files, you could just update the file `styles.xml` in the archive with one of your own. To create your own style-sheet, edit your .odt file and edit only the existing global styles.